# .htaccess change wordpress hompage but keep the link

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, web, server

`example.com/wp`
or
`example.com/wp/`

<- This is what homepage link used to be like and I'm trying to keep it this way.
But I want the server to serve some static page from another subfolder as a front page (but to keep all the other wp contents at the same places)

My static page (several of them tbh) are stored in root/subf1/

I was able to redirect to the desired subfolder, but the path also shows up in the URL. 
Is it possible to change example.com/subf1 to example/wp?

Here's my current htaccess. Maybe I need to create another one in a static page folder?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subf1/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/page/$1
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
      RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /subf1/index.html [L] 
 </IfModule>

RedirectMatch "^/wp$" "https://example.com/subf1/"
```

Thank you a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

RedirectMatch does only "external redirections", so you probably want internal redirection with a RewriteRule (without the R flag).

So instead of RedirectMatch try:

```
RewriteRule ^wp$ https://example.com/subf1/ [L]
```

PS: Generally it is good to go for redirect/redirectmatch instead of going for mod_rewrite, but if you are already using mod_rewrite directives it will be less confusing to stick to it and not mix direcitves from one or the other.

Comment: I also think that plain redirects is easier to maintain but...
Now not only home page from /wp/ but all the other older pages are getting redirected to /subf1/

That's the code that I'm using
`
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^wp/$ /subf1/
`

Is it possible to only redirect the homepage (which used to open when you access /wp/) but leave requests like wp/?page_id=12
unprocessed?

Comment: you will need to check for query_string in your rewriteconds to do that